# wpf - CellEditingTemplate in a DataGrid Edit mode problem

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a DataGrid with CellEditingTemplate ,
How can i force the first cell of the DataGridRow to enter edit mode when a row is loaded.
I tried a few things but nothing seems to work..
thanks..

Comment: Implementing this is not difficult but row loading is a tricky business in Virtualized environment like datagrid's items. Because when we scroll up and down, rows which were previously loaded will load again and thus put their first cells in edit mode. So you will have some rows which are newly scrolled into view, with their first cells in edit mode. Is this what you want?

Comment: It doesn't have to be on row loaded event,all i want is the first cell of the first row to be in edit mode- it's a costumer request.

Comment: Oh and more thing i forgot to mention, i'm using mvvm.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridCell has IsEditing property, which if you set to true puts the cell in edit mode. So in the first column put this true in a style targetted to the datagrid cell type...

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn ...>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
               <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
         </Style>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: If it doesnt work in Style (by direct setting IsEditing) then you can try doing it using attached behavior. IsEditing is a settable dependency property and I have used it many a times to put a cell in Edit mode.

Comment: I've tried using behavior as well, i made a datagrid behavior , and registerd to the rowloading event , but i had problems getting the DataGridCell out of the DataGridRow, in order to set the IsEditing prop on the cell it self , any pointers?

Comment: you can handle the Loaded event of DataGridCell in the same Style above.... <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="DataGridCellLoaded" />